# Core Data one-to-many sorting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have `CoreData` object "Entity" with `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *ImagesSet;`

Inside ImagesSet are many "ImageEntity" objects.

"ImageEntity" have `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * sortKey;`

How create fetchRequest for "Entity" with imagesSet ordered by sortKey field?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] mainObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSString * predicate = some predicate string......;
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:2500];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:25];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ImageEntity.sortKey" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = nil;

 frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:mainObjectContext
                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                     cacheName:cashName];
```

Program crashes with message "***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'**"

Comment: If you remove the `sortDescriptor`, does it works? I suspect that the real issue could be your predicate.

Comment: The sort descriptor is the problem.  In SQL, you'd need to select the sort column and use a `group by` and aggregate to get a single value to sort by.  With `NSPredicate` and `NSSortDescriptor` there's no way to specify this kind of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch `Entity` objects, there is no way to control the order of the related `ImageEntity` objects *as part of the fetch*.  You have a few options instead:

1. Specify in your data model that the relationship is ordered.  The relationship will be represented as `NSOrderedSet` instead of `NSSet`.  You will have to ensure that the set is ordered as you need (instead of using `sortKey`).
2. Keep the relationship as unordered (`NSSet`), and sort the set when you need to.  Eg.

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor *imageSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortKey" ascending:NO];
   NSArray *sortedImages = [myEntity.imagesSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[imageSort]];
   ```
3. Fetch the `ImageEntity` objects directly, using a predicate to filter the results to the relevant `Entity` object, and the required sort descriptor:

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor *imageSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortKey" ascending:NO];
   NSFetchRequest *imageFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ImageEntity"];
   imageFetch.sortDescriptors = @[imageSort];
   imageFetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity == %@",myEntity];
   NSError *error;
   NSArray *sortedImages = [context executeFetchRequest:imageFetch error:&error];
   ```