# How to sort related objects in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a many to many relationship in Core Data with posts and tags. Each tag has many posts and each post has many tags. I have a view controller where I want to display, for a particular tag, all of the posts associated with it.

I do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //2
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
        //3
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Tag.name == %@", tag.name!)
//        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
//        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil) as? NSFetchedResultsController<Tag>
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            tag = fetchedResultsController.object(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
            tag = Tag(context: managedContext)
            let posts = tag.posts
```

My posts object at the bottom is a Set of objects - unordered. I want an array of posts ordered by timestamp that all belong to this particular tag and Im not sure how to create that.

I know usually to sort items by timestamp you would introduce an NSSortDescriptor like I did in step 3 (but is commented out). But I believe this would sort my fetch request (Tag) by the Tag's timestamp. Each tag doesn't have a timestamp and what I really want to sort is the posts associated with that tag. So I don't believe this is the way to do this.

How do I go about this? I think I could just use swift but it feels like there must be a Core Data way to sort related objects by timestamp

Edit: Updated approach with Paulw11's advice:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //2
        let tagFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
        let postFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Post> = Post.fetchRequest()
        //3
        tagFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Tag.name), tag.name!)

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(tagFetchRequest)
            tag = results.first
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Tag Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        guard let tag = tag else { return }

        postFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN Post.tags", tag)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
        postFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: postFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            posts = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [Post]
            firstPostDate = posts.first?.timeStamp as Date?
            lastPostDate = posts.last?.timeStamp as Date?
            for (i,post) in posts.enumerated() {
                let date = post.timeStamp as Date?
                let day = date?.days(from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: firstPostDate!))
                indexMap[day!] = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
            }
```

This gives this error message:

```
2018-11-29 15:36:56.261887-0800 SweatNetOffline[31250:17419187] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (<Tag: 0x60000216b2a0> (entity: Tag; id: 0xc36a752f5b05e34c <x-coredata://F02C5E33-89B9-4814-9D1B-8C74CAEC7DA1/Tag/p79> ; data: {
    mostRecentThumbnail = nil;
    mostRecentUpdate = "2018-12-07 21:47:44 +0000";
    name = test;
    posts =     (
        "0xc36a752f5af9e34e <x-coredata://F02C5E33-89B9-4814-9D1B-8C74CAEC7DA1/Post/p48>"
    );
    uuid = nil;
}) IN Post.tags)'
```

Looks like its inserting that entire object into the query string. This seems wrong but maybe I need to format the object differently?

Comment: It seems you want a `Post.fetchRequest` and then set the predicate to `format: "Post.tag.name == %@"`. Then `NSSortDescriptor("timeStamp")` applies the way you want. I don't know CoreData well enough to propose this as an answer but as long as keyPaths can be more than one `.` level lookup this should work.

Comment: @BaseZen but there is no Post.tag... There is Post.tags. What about something like         fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN Post.tags", tag.name!)

Comment: That works, but looks a lot slower at scale though given *O*(|P| x |T|) searching Also question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605140/core-data-one-to-many-sorting

Comment: I get a crash and  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : ("test2" IN Post.tags)'.  "test2" is the name of the tag. When you say "slower than", what is it slower than?

Comment: `post.tags`is a reference, so your predicate needs to supply an instance of a `Tag` entity, not the tag's name.  You first need to fetch the actual `Tag` instance by name (if you don't already have it) and then use that in your `NSPredicate`

Comment: @Paulw11 so would the instance supplied by an NSManagedObject or a Tag object?

Comment: A `Tag` should be an `NSManagedObject` subclass. Xcode will generate the subclasses based on your entities

Comment: @Paulw11 check out the edit in the question and the error code it's giving. I believe that tag object is the NSManagedObject subclass. Is this the approach you were thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to use         `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN self.tags", tag)`

as opposed to         `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN Post.tags", tag)`

The context of the predicate is the Post so it no longer needs to be accessed I suppose, it is assumed. Self.tags, tags, and SELF.tags all work.